# Is there any Android game framework ready to use

Tags: android, frameworks

Do you know any tile based game framework for android like [HGE](http://hge.relishgames.com/) for PC or at least some good examples of tile based engine for Android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/

http://www.andengine.org/

http://code.google.com/p/rokon/

give it a try...

This other is coming soon: http://www.typhon4android.org/

Comment: Could you update the link please?

Comment: Project is now at http://code.google.com/p/rokon/ - however due to a server fault, it is no longer in development. [http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) seems the closest alternative.

Comment: you can see here even more game engines for android:
http://mobilegameengines.com/android/game_engines

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://privateasteroid.com/2010/07/19/android-open-source-game-engines/) you can find a list of a few engines, including above, I prefer libgdx

Answer (score 1):

I found this one: [Andengine](http://www.andengine.org). I believe it's under the LGPL license, which is great, but I cannot tell how good it is yet. The code seems to be pretty clean and clear, though.